# how to solve error Xcode signing and capabilities

Tags: ios, xcode, signing

I can't solve this error. Added my account (Apple ID) but still getting error.

How can i solve this ?
[image]

Comment: Which error are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about the status. See the screenshot, said "Failed to create...." and the second  error.

Comment: "Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it" - did you try that?

Comment: Hmm I didn't got it. Can you give me an example ? Thank you

Comment: Connect your device to your mac and then click on that "Try Again" button!

Comment: Great! So the problem was this. I should connect my real device with my Mac. Works perfectly! Thank you very much!